# ssh config for multiple hops plus "sudo su"

Tags: ssh

I have a particular setup that requires this sequence of steps:

```
ssh me@host1
ssh me@host2
sudo su otheruser
```

I have:

- an ssh key on my laptop that allows me to `ssh me@host1`
- an ssh key on host1 that allows me to `ssh me@host2`.

I do **not** have permission to `ssh otheruser@host2`.

My goal is: can I automate this? Preferably in my laptop's ~/.ssh/config file, so I can simply do:

```
ssh otheruser
```

...and let the config take care of the details, ideally including the password?

I can already get 2/3 of the way there with the following ssh config:

```
Host host1
HostName host1.example.com

Host host2
HostName host2.example.com

Host mostly_there
HostName host2.example.com
ProxyJump host1 host2
```

The above allows me to `ssh mostly_there` but I still have to `sudo su otheruser`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this in .ssh/config:

```
HOST host1
  user me

HOST host2
    USER me
    ProxyCommand ssh host1 -W %h:%p

HOST otheruser
    USER me
    ProxyCommand ssh host1 -W %h:%p
    RemoteCommand sudo su -c '/bin/bash -i' otheruser
```

To connect to host2 with user otheruser just use:

```
ssh otheruser
```

It currently has the drawback, that it isn't a full interactive shell, but that could be fixed by a better invocation than `/bin/bash -i`

Comment: By "add your public key to that user", which public key do you mean? Right now I have a key on my laptop, and a different key on host1 that allows me to ssh into host2.

Comment: I updated my question to be more explicit about my permissions. I can't `ssh otheruser@host2` from any host, which is why I have ssh and su split into 2 steps.

Comment: @AlexShroyer You don't need to `ssh otheruser@host2`, that's the point of the `ProxyCommand` it uses host1 as an jump box. You should add your public key from your laptop to host2, it's a bad idea to store a private key on a middle host (host1 in your case)

Comment: `RequestTTY yes` will help get an interactive shell

Answer (score 0):

If you have root you can deploy your public key to `otheruser`'s
authorized_keys and login without using a password. After switching to
`otheruser` do this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
```

and put your public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. You should now be able to log in remotely
as `otheruser` just by doing `ssh otheruser@host`.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` can be used to copy the ssh key. It just requires that sshd lets you log in via password as the other user (in some configurations a user is not allowed to log in via password or at all in sshd_config).

Comment: I updated my question to clarify why this does not work for me. In short, I don't have permission to log in as `otheruser`, nor do I have general sudo permissions. I can `sudo su otheruser`, but that's about it.

Comment: @AlexShroyer: but if you can become `otheruser` on the remote server you can deploy your local user's public key to authorized_keys.

Comment: `oheruser` does not have ssh access